# Button change value from database row

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a button that when i click it to change a specific value from specific column and row from database acording to "id"

This is my database name: highmob_comenzi
table: players 
Column: statuscomandamobila

The current value from that column is "necomandat" 
each row is auto_increment by an ID
Im trying to create a button that when i click it to change the value from comumn "statuscomandamobila" from "necomandat" to "in lucru"

Im really sorry that i haven't any code but i got no ideea where to start!

I do have the connection to the database :( and a button where i can see the page acordint to ID

```
 echo "<td class='text-center'><a target='_blank'  class='btn btn-sm btn-
 info' href='edit.php?id=" . $value['id'] . "'> Vezi Comanda</a></td>\n";
```

This is the code from PHP with a button that actually let me see the page acording to that ID :)

Comment: you need an UPDATE statement for this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html - seems to be what the post is about.

Comment: see, but how do i create a button that update a value from database?

Any ideea where to start? Because this button also have to be in " echo 'button'

Comment: You must remove double quotes from id  url query param

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `edit.php`:

```
echo "<td class='text-center'><a class='btn btn-sm btn-info' href='update_comanada.php?id=" . $_GET['id'] . "'> UPDATE COMANDA</a></td>\n";
```

Try something like this in `update_comanda.php` (edit connection parameters first):

```
try {
 if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
     $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
     $id = $_GET["id"];

     $sql = "UPDATE `players` SET `statuscomandamobila`= 'in lucru' WHERE `id`=:id";       

     $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
     $statement->bindValue(":id", $id);
     $count = $statement->execute();

     $conn = null;        // Disconnect
  }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Allright so il create a new page nammed update_comanda.php and  paste the code what u gaved me editing ofc the mysql host parameter. Il check it and paste the results

Answer (score 0):

Try this, pasting into your edit.php:

```
  <?php
    //Using $db as the connection to your database
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
       $id = intval($_GET['id']);
       $sql = "UPDATE players SET statuscomandamobila =  'in lucru' WHERE id = $id";
       mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Well i see the code but this is not a button, or i should create a page nammed edit.php and redirect the button to that page and also make the mysql connection, am i right?